# Round Image File

Tags: flutter, dart, bitmap, paint, uint8array

I did this code to get an image from firestore and use it as an icon for a Map Marker.

```
final StorageReference storageReference =
FirebaseStorage().ref().child("ProfilePictures/" + widget.userId);
String avatarDownloadPath = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
final File _avatar = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(avatarDownloadPath);
Uint8List __avatar = await _avatar.readAsBytes();
BitmapDescriptor avatar = BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(__avatar);

setState(() {
  _markers.add(Marker(markerId: MarkerId("UserPosition"), position: userLocation, icon: avatar ));
});
```

This code works but I want to set the image a round shape and I don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use use Canvas to draw a round image and use PictureRecorder to save as a final image and put it in the marker bitmapdescriptor, fyi: [custom marker](https://coletiv.com/blog/customize-your-cluster-markers-on-flutter-google-maps/)

Replace TextPainter with ImagePainter in the article

OR

Follow this article by using widget, [custom marker](https://infinum.com/the-capsized-eight/creating-custom-markers-on-google-maps-in-flutter-apps)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @Jim Chiu, here my implementation:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

Future<BitmapDescriptor> convertImageFileToCustomBitmapDescriptor(File imageFile,
    {int size = 150,
    bool addBorder = false,
    Color borderColor = Colors.white,
    double borderSize = 10,
    String title,
    Color titleColor = Colors.white,
    Color titleBackgroundColor = Colors.black}) async {
  final ui.PictureRecorder pictureRecorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  final Canvas canvas = Canvas(pictureRecorder);
  final Paint paint = Paint()..color;
  final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  );
  final double radius = size / 2;

  //make canvas clip path to prevent image drawing over the circle
  final Path clipPath = Path();
  clipPath.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.toDouble(), size.toDouble()),
      Radius.circular(100)));
  clipPath.addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
      Rect.fromLTWH(0, size * 8 / 10, size.toDouble(), size * 3 / 10),
      Radius.circular(100)));
  canvas.clipPath(clipPath);

  //paintImage
  final Uint8List imageUint8List = await imageFile.readAsBytes();
  final ui.Codec codec = await ui.instantiateImageCodec(imageUint8List);
  final ui.FrameInfo imageFI = await codec.getNextFrame();
  paintImage(
      canvas: canvas,
      rect: Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.toDouble(), size.toDouble()),
      image: imageFI.image);

  if (addBorder) {
    //draw Border
    paint..color = borderColor;
    paint..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    paint..strokeWidth = borderSize;
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(radius, radius), radius, paint);
  }

  if (title != null) {
    if (title.length > 9) {
      title = title.substring(0, 9);
    }
    //draw Title background
    paint..color = titleBackgroundColor;
    paint..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    canvas.drawRRect(
        RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
            Rect.fromLTWH(0, size * 8 / 10, size.toDouble(), size * 3 / 10),
            Radius.circular(100)),
        paint);

    //draw Title
    textPainter.text = TextSpan(
        text: title,
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: radius / 2.5,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: titleColor,
        ));
    textPainter.layout();
    textPainter.paint(
        canvas,
        Offset(radius - textPainter.width / 2,
            size * 9.5 / 10 - textPainter.height / 2));
  }

  //convert canvas as PNG bytes
  final _image =
      await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(size, (size * 1.1).toInt());
  final data = await _image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

  //convert PNG bytes as BitmapDescriptor
  return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(data.buffer.asUint8List());
}
```

and here the result:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your complete code because I want to know how you implemented Future<BitmapDescriptor> as Marker Icon.

Comment: You need to get the bitmap descriptor [asynchronously](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await). It will look like this: `BitmapDescriptor myBitmap = await convertImageFileToCustomBitmapDescriptor(File imageFile)`. After this you can assign `myBitmap` to your Marker object.

Comment: Tried but didn't worked that's why I was asking for github

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://github.com/Milvintsiss/the_spot/blob/bdb89bdc14d449406aae1bbfb60f4d4dec773f32/lib/pages/map_pages/map.dart#L228) but this code is old and not well organized. Note that in my code I  did a class to pass argument to the function but you do not need this.

Comment: I will check this code and I'm sure this will help me. Thanks man!

Comment: @ArslanKaleem If you want help with personal issues you have to open a question dedicated, include a snippet of your code and explain your problem in it. Comment section is not really dedicated to this type of answer ;)

Comment: can you tell me if I want to increase the width of text like if i want to print 100 character text then what i have to change ? 
I have changed many fields but cannot succeed.

Comment: @MuhammadTameemRafay You can decrease the "fontSize" if you want the text to be smaller, if you want to increase the size of the rounded rectangle behind this will be more tricky because you will have to resize the whole image. I encourage you to understand the code by doing researches on flutter painter, if you need any help understanding don't hesitate to ask here.

Answer (score -4):

Have you tried this?

```
Material(
  elevation: 4.0,
  shape: CircleBorder(),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: Ink.image(
    image: AssetImage('assets/profile_default.jpg'),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
    width: 120.0,
    height: 120.0,
    child: InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
    ),
  ),
)
```