# pictureRecorder.endRecording creates "Minified:vs" instead of "CkPicture" on Flutter Web Mobile

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using a PictureRecorder variable from the dart:ui package for creating an image with this line of code:

```
final _image =
      await pictureRecorder.endRecording().toImage(size, (size * 1.1).toInt());
```

It works fine with Flutter Android, Flutter iOS and also Flutter Web. But I experienced a problem with Flutter Web, if it is opened with any mobile device (iOS and Android).

The problem is that endRecording doesn't create an "Instance of CkPicture". Instead it creates an "Instance of Minified:vs", whatever that means. But only on Flutter Web if you open with a mobile phone.

And ideas for a fix or a workaround?

Here's a complete example for this code for converting an image to a png
[Round Image File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61174307/round-image-file/71894662#71894662)